# How to measure IOPS for a Cassandra stress test?

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2, cassandra, stress-testing

I've been running some basic stress test against a 3 node Cassandra cluster with replication 1 and 3.  The system is Linux and on SAN.  Am also doing a comparison on EC2 with SSD storage.  The duration of 1M records on writes/reads is much faster on local SAN network versus SSD on EC2.

However, I'm still not sure exactly how to best measure overall IOPS performance between the two systems while a stress test is running.  Other than iowait, are there any other tools I can use?

The systems have large amount of memory so I would expect the IOPS to be low as the system disks would not be used due to all activity being in memory, am I wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Do not run Cassandra on a SAN.  Your memtable flushes will take WAY longer than they need to, and may cause your node to appear down.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, install [Datastax OpsCenter](http://www.datastax.com/what-we-offer/products-services/datastax-opscenter) on the cluster and while running the stress test go to the OpsCenter dashboard and you can look the IOPS graph in realtime.

Hope it helps!